# JSON response help grabbing each pair

Tags: json, swift, parsing

**JSON Response**

```
["Tidex": {
    AE =     (
        ETH,
        BTC
    );
    AGI =     (
        ETH,
        USDT,
        BTC
    );
    AHT =     (
        BTC,
        WAVES
    );
}]
```

**HTTP Request**

```
   let url = URL(string: "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/all/exchanges")! //change the url

    //create the session object
    let session = URLSession.shared

    //now create the URLRequest object using the url object
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)

    //create dataTask using the session object to send data to the server
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

        guard error == nil else {
            return
        }

        guard let data = data else {
            return
        }

        do {
            //create json object from data
            if var json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
                if (!json.isEmpty) {
                    print(json)

                }

            }
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
    task.resume()
```

I don't recognise the '=' and ';' and not sure how to grab the data so i can organise as i desire. What I'd like to do is to organise the data into their pairs as shown below

> AE/ETH AE/BTC
>
> AGI/ETH AGI/USDT AGI/BTC
>
> AHT/BTC AHT/WAVES

Comment: The JSON you posted is not valid, is it a printed decoded object?

Comment: yes. You can run the code yourself to see the output

Comment: Please place the JSON then in the question, or update it to not reference JSON, as currently there's no such thing in the post.

Comment: I've placed the JSON response at the top of the question, the remaining JSON is repeated pattern with different symbols. I don't see a reason why it had to be marked down.

Comment: With all due respect, the question doesn't contain any valid JSON. The snippet at the beginning of the question is not a JSON. BTW, it wasn't me who downvoted.

Comment: You're right, it isn't valid JSON. I keep thinking it is because Swift doesn't seem to have any trouble parsing it. No worries, I wasn't saying it was you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to decode the JSON with `Decodable` to an umbrella struct including a dictionary with string array value

```
struct Root : Decodable {

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case tidex = "Tidex" }

    let tidex : [String:[String]]
}
```

---

```
...

do {
    //create json object from data
    let root = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
    for (key, value) in root.tidex {
        print("key", key, "value", value)
    }

} catch {
     print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

And – as always – `.mutableContainers` is pointless in Swift.

Comment: Sorry the late response. I've only had time to get back to it today and marked this as the solution. It's worked great.